# What does "of working age" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

I have to answer the following question, and I don't understand what it means.

> Are you a dependent of a person who is or will be working in Canada and you're of working age?

- What does it mean by  "are you a dependent of a person who is or will be working in Canada? Does "dependent of" mean "responsible for" here?
- What does it mean by "of working age"?  Does it mean "in the age of serving as employee"? (Say, from 20 years old to 60 years old.)

Answer (score 5):

> Are you a dependent of a person who is or will be working in Canada?

This means: *Are you being supported (financially) by a person who is or will be working in Canada?*

If someone is supporting someone else who lives with them, say a boyfriend or a friend down on her luck, they might be able to claim that person as **a dependent**. It doesn't necessarily have to be someone related to them.

> Are you of working age?

This simply means: Are you old enough to legally work (under Canadian laws I presume)?